# Is it good practice to allow multiple types of argument in python

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django project. In a function that I'm writing that uses an instance of `myModel`, I'm considering allowing passing that instance to the function directly or passing the private key of that instance and making a query to retrieve the instance:

```
def myFunction(IdOrObj):
    myObj = myModel.objects.get(pk=IdOrObj) if isinstance(IdOrObj, int) else IdOrObj
    ...
```

Is this bad practice? If so, what are the reasons and what are some alternatives?

Comment: While this is acceptable, It is a good idea to restrict the types. Example, I would just do `if isinstance(IdOrObj, int)` and also check `isinstance(IdOrObj, MyModel)` If both conditions are not met, raise an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that this approach tends to make the code fairly ugly. once you start doing this in multiple places, many of your functions will look like this:

```
def myFunction(StrangeMetaObject):
    if isinstance(StrangeMetaObject, int):
        # Do the 
    elif isinstance(StrangeMetaObject, str):
        # Do the str thing...
    elif isinstance(StrangeMetaObject, MyObject):
        # ...
```

You also get cases where the calling code wants to pass in something that looks the same, but doesn't share any part of the inheritance hierarchy. For example, this should be allowed:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Fox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()

def print_age(IdOrObj):
    # This will fail if passed a Fox
    myObj = Person.objects.get(pk=IdOrObj) if isinstance(IdOrObj, int) else IdOrObj
    print('%s is %s years old' % (myObj.name, myObj.age))
```

For your use case I suggest you always pass around Django models, there is rarely a good reason to work with IDs.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, it could get messy fast.